# How should I import the array data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase to store form's data. when I am trying to import the data, I couldn't import the arrays items.
the code is:

```
{info.map((infos) => (
  <tr>
    <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Name}</td>
    <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.ID}</td>
    <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Email}</td>
    <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Telephone}</td>
    <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Branch.label}</td>
    <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Voted.label}</td>
  </tr>
))}
```

[image: first data]
[image: second data]

[image: third data]

[image: table result]

I tried to add :

```
<td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Voted.map.label}</td>
<td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Voted.array.label}</td>
<td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Voted.label[Object]}</td>
<td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Voted.array[label]}</td>
```

but also no results. I am new firebase user so any suggestion or help?

Comment: what's the value of info once you log it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

infos.data.Voted is array of objects, so you can use like this

```
{info.map((infos) => (
        <tr>
          <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Name}</td>
          <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.ID}</td>
          <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Email}</td>
          <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Telephone}</td>
          <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Branch.label}</td>
          <td key={infos.id}>{infos.data.Voted.map((v)=> v.label).join(",")}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
```